# Are there text editors for macOS that use `GtkSourceView`?

Tags: macos, text-editors, gtk, right-to-left, arabic

I'm looking for a text editor for macOS that has decent RTL (Arabic) support.

As far as I can tell, `GtkSourceView` is one of the few (if not only) editor technologies that support RTL editing properly.

However, being on macOS, it's not easy to find such text editors that work smoothly on macOS.

`gedit` sort of works, but the menu items on the topbar don't work, so it's impossible to use it for serious editing.

Answer (score 0):

This Wikipedia page is actively maintained, and includes a section for RTL support: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_text_editors#Right-to-left_and_bidirectional_text

The editors there are are for many platforms, though, so you'll need to cross-reference the RTL table with the OS Support table.  But, there are several for the Mac listed.  I just don't know how good any of them are at RTL.